# Arm does not appear when using xacro to attach UR5 to Robotiq Gripper

Tags: gazebo, ros-melodic, gripper, universal-robot, xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to attach a Robotiq 2f gripper to a UR5 arm, but cannot get the two components to properly connect to one another. Following the tutorial [here](http://wiki.ros.org/Industrial/Tutorials/WorkingWithRosIndustrialRobotSupportPackages#Example:_adding_an_end-effector_to_a_robot), I created the xacro file below, but only the gripper appears when I launch the MoveIt Setup Assistant and load the xacro. I don't see any errors.

How do I properly attach the gripper to the arm for simulation?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot name="ur5_robotiq" xmlns:xacro="http://wiki.ros.org/xacro">
<!-- include macros for UR5 and the 2f gripper -->

<xacro:include filename="$(find ur_description)/urdf/ur5.urdf.xacro" />
<xacro:include filename="$(find robotiq_2f_140_gripper_visualization)/urdf/robotiq_arg2f_140_model.xacro" />

<!-- create the robot + eef combo itself as a macro -->
<xacro:macro name="ee_robot" params="prefix">

<!-- instantiate UR5 and 2f gripper -->
  <xacro:ur5_robot prefix="${prefix}robot_" joint_limited="true"/>
  <xacro:robotiq_arg2f_140 prefix="${prefix}gripper_" />

  <!-- attach gripper -->
  <joint name="${prefix}robot_tool0-${prefix}gripper_robotiq_arg2f_base_link" type="fixed">
    <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="${pi/2} -${pi/2} 0" />
    <parent link="${prefix}robot_tool0" />
    <child link="${prefix}gripper_robotiq_arg2f_base_link" />
  </joint>

 </xacro:macro>
</robot>
```

I have cloned the most recent industrial packages for Universal Robots and Robotiq and am running Ubuntu 18.04.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/310297/arm-does-not-appear-when-using-xacro-to-attach-ur5-to-robotiq-gripper/) by [ceres](https://answers.ros.org/users/38931/ceres/) on ROS Answers with karma: 86 on 2018-12-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-12-10**:
Can you please check whether you're running into [ros/urdfdom_headers#41](https://github.com/ros/urdfdom_headers/issues/41)?

Also: if you don't create the joint, nor instantiate the `robotiq_arg2f_140` macro, does the robot model appear?

**Comment by [ceres](https://answers.ros.org/users/38931/ceres/) on 2018-12-10**:
I don't think the urdfdom_headers issue is the problem here, and I've tried changing the `pi/2` values to `0` with no effect.
Also, yes the robot model appears if I remove the joint and the `robotiq_arg2f_140`.

**Comment by [ceres](https://answers.ros.org/users/38931/ceres/) on 2018-12-10**:
Also, I added `<xacro:ee_robot prefix=""/>` below the macro to create the arm + gripper combo, and the resulting error is now as follows:

`[ERROR] [1544424525.498517311]: Failed to find root link: Two root links found: [robot_base_link] and [robotiq_arg2f_base_link]`

**Comment by [ceres](https://answers.ros.org/users/38931/ceres/) on 2018-12-10**:
I was able to fix arm not showing up by using `robotiq_arg2f_140_model_macro.xacro`
instead of `robotiq_arg2f_140_model.xacro`. However, the planning group for `gripper` only shows 1 of the 8 gripper finger joints. I don't know if this is a related  issue or if I should create a new question for t

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-12-10**:
Ah:

1. I assumed you were instantiating your xacro macro somewhere else
2. I also assumed you were using the correct files (the one with the macro definition, not the top-level one)

re: planning group: did you create that yourself?

In any case: yes, that would be a new question.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-12-10**:
Finally: please post how you resolved this as an answer and accept your own answer.

**Comment by [ceres](https://answers.ros.org/users/38931/ceres/) on 2018-12-10**:
Thanks. I've already posted the answer, but I don't have enough reputation to accept it yet.

**Comment by [ceres](https://answers.ros.org/users/38931/ceres/) on 2018-12-10**:
I was trying to create the planning group in the MoveIt Setup Assistant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The fix for this was to add `<xacro:ee_robot prefix=""/>` after the macro for the gripper attachment, and to use `robotiq_arg2f_140_model_macro.xacro` instead of `robotiq_arg2f_140_model.xacro`. The working macro looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot name="ur5_robotiq" xmlns:xacro="http://wiki.ros.org/xacro">
<!-- include macros for UR5 and the 2f gripper -->

<xacro:include filename="$(find ur_description)/urdf/ur5.urdf.xacro" />
<xacro:include filename="$(find robotiq_2f_140_gripper_visualization)/urdf/robotiq_arg2f_140_model_macro.xacro" />

<!-- create the robot + eef combo itself as a macro -->
<xacro:macro name="ee_robot" params="prefix">

<!-- instantiate UR5 and 2f gripper -->
  <xacro:ur5_robot prefix="${prefix}robot_" joint_limited="true"/>
  <xacro:robotiq_arg2f_140 prefix="${prefix}gripper_" />

  <!-- attach gripper -->
  <joint name="${prefix}robot_tool0-${prefix}gripper_robotiq_arg2f_base_link" type="fixed">
    <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="${pi/2} -${pi/2} 0" />
    <parent link="${prefix}robot_tool0" />
    <child link="${prefix}gripper_robotiq_arg2f_base_link" />
  </joint>

 </xacro:macro>
<xacro:ee_robot prefix=""/>
</robot>
```

---

Originally posted by [ceres](https://answers.ros.org/users/38931/ceres/) with karma: 86 on 2018-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [madhav](https://answers.ros.org/users/104620/madhav/) on 2022-05-11**:
Failed to find root link: Two root links found: [base_link] and [robot_base_link]
I am always getting this, how can it be solved?